# smop has issues when translating a >= statment in MATLAB

Tags: python, matlab

I'm using SMOP version 0.41 to translate my MATLAB code to anaconda python however
whenever there is a statement with a greater or equal to statment for example:

if numFFT >= 2

I get the following error

SyntaxError: Unexpected "=" (parser)

Has anyone experienced this?

Answer (score 0):

you can simply edit lexer.py for greater or equal by putting "\" in front of "<" or ">".

example: 
from "<="
to "\<=" or "<\=", both of them works the same on your converted python code.